# ansible loop over ip addresses in variable file instead of inventory

Tags: ansible

i am having an issue where playbooks are executed multiple times.I have ip address of servers set in inventory as well as in variable file.

```
---
- hosts: servers
gather_facts: no
vars_files:
- input.yml
tasks:

- name: Powering On Servers
  local_action: ipmitool -I lanplus -H {{item.consoleofserver}} -U {{item.consoleuser}} -P {{item.consolepassword}} power on
  with_items:
   - "{{ computeserver }}"


- name: Waiting for Servers to be up
   local_action:
   wait_for
   host={{ item.ipaddress }}
   port=22
   delay=10
   timeout=3600
  sudo: false
  with_items:
   - "{{ computeserver }}"

- name: Configuring ip address on application
 lineinfile:
   state=present
   create=yes
   dest=/etc/app/app.conf
   regexp='^my_ip =.*'
   line='my_ip = {{item.ipaddress}}'
 with_items:
    - "{{ computeserver }}"
 when: ansible_nodename == item.name
```

variable file - input.yml

```
---

computeserver:
- name: compute4
  ipaddress: 192.168.211.251
  console: 192.168.211.10
  consoleuser: administrator
  consolepassword: 1


- name: compute5
  ipaddress: 192.168.211.253
  console: 192.168.211.11
  consoleuser: administrator
  consolepassword: 1

- name: compute6
  ipaddress: 192.168.211.252
  console: 192.168.211.12
  consoleuser: administrator
  consolepassword: 1
```

inventory file:

```
[servers]
192.168.211.251
192.168.211.253
192.168.211.252
```

Result:

**ansible-playbook addserver.yml**

```
TASK: [Powering ON Servers]   ***************************************************
changed: [192.168.211.251 -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'console': '192.168.211.10', 'consolepassword': 1, 'ipaddress': '192.168.211.251', 'name': 'compute4', 'consoleuser': 'administrator'})
changed: [192.168.211.253 -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'console': '192.168.211.10', 'consolepassword': 1, 'ipaddress': '192.168.211.251', 'name': 'compute4', 'consoleuser': 'administrator'})
changed: [192.168.211.252 -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'console': '192.168.211.10', 'consolepassword': 1, 'ipaddress': '192.168.211.251', 'name': 'compute4', 'consoleuser': 'administrator'})
changed: [192.168.211.251 -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'console': '192.168.211.11', 'consolepassword': 1, 'ipaddress': '192.168.211.253', 'name': 'compute5', 'consoleuser': 'administrator'})
changed: [192.168.211.253 -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'console': '192.168.211.11', 'consolepassword': 1, 'ipaddress': '192.168.211.253', 'name': 'compute5', 'consoleuser': 'administrator'})
changed: [192.168.211.252 -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'console': '192.168.211.11', 'consolepassword': 1, 'ipaddress': '192.168.211.253', 'name': 'compute5', 'consoleuser': 'administrator'})
changed: [192.168.211.251 -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'console': '192.168.211.12', 'consolepassword': 1, 'ipaddress': '192.168.211.252', 'name': 'compute6', 'consoleuser': 'administrator'})
changed: [192.168.211.253 -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'console': '192.168.211.12', 'consolepassword': 1, 'ipaddress': '192.168.211.252', 'name': 'compute6', 'consoleuser': 'administrator'})
changed: [192.168.211.252 -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'console': '192.168.211.12', 'consolepassword': 1, 'ipaddress': '192.168.211.252', 'name': 'compute6', 'consoleuser': 'administrator'})
```

So instead of adding servers in inventory file can i tell ansible to use ip address defined in variable file to use as target servers,this may fix looping over same server again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit a task to be only executed once, with the [`run_once` property](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once).

```
- name: Powering On Servers
  local_action: ipmitool -I lanplus -H {{item.consoleofserver}} -U {{item.consoleuser}} -P {{item.consolepassword}} power on
  run_once: true
  with_items: computeserver
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the [`add_host` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html).

You should be able to do something like this:

```
- hosts:
  - localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
  - input.yml
  tasks:
  - add_host: hostname={{ item.ipaddress }} groups=generated_group
    with_items: computeserver

- hosts: generated_group
  tasks:
  ... your other tasks
```

Comment: thanks again,am i doing something wrong here.With generated_group now i have new group with set of servers created without adding individual ip to inventory that is a cool  module :)  
but i still have the old issue of  playbooks being executed multiple times.
changed playbook: http://ur1.ca/ndabl
One thing i noticed is,if there are 4 nodes mentioned in variable file then each task will be executed 4 times!! .Any idea about this behaviour

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question. Might it be there is a `with_items` element missing in the first task? Because the way it is I can not explain the output you posted.

Comment: I added another answer which hopefully addresses the question. :) Leaving this one here for reference.

Comment: ahh sorry i corrected that ,its there in actual playbook but while copy pasting i missed that.Tasks are getting executed as expected only problem is its executing each task 4 times if there are 4 hosts defined in variable file.